# Is there interest in sharing book reviews here?

Tags: discussion

I recently bought two books on UX with similar titles and have been considering blogging my review of them on my own blog and/or LinkedIn.
It occurs to me this site might be a better place for it.

Is there any interest in sharing book reviews or is a review the wrong kind of content for UX Stack Exchanges ask-answer model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

That's not really what this site is for. Stack Exchange sites are Question and Answer sites - a question is posed that is based on an actual problem that that person has, and any responses to that question are the form of an answer that gives the solution to that issue.

Book reviews do not fit into that format, so are not suitable to this site.